# Putting a toolbar above the split view

Tags: ios, user-interface, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

How do you go about it? To give you an idea, it's like that toolbar on this eBay iPad app. Notice on the last photo the split view is gone but the toolbar is still there? I wonder if the whole thing is controlled by a UI navigation? Or is it much more technical than that?

Source:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ebay-for-ipad/id364203371?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

i have done a similar thing which acts as a toolbar and in real its not. i have added a        image  of tool bar length and added the remaining buttons and functionalities accordingly on it making the image view as (push background) transparent.
and the rest follows the navigation controller and split view controller.